# 301 redirect on IIS with optional query string

Tags: iis, redirect, 301-redirect

I have a working 301 redirect setup for languages that looks like this:

```
<rule name="mygreatrule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^productname" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?example1.com$" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="lang=(de|fr|is|es)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example2.com/abcd/{C:1}/product/myproduct/productname" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

But this works for example for URLs like

```
https://www.example1.com/productname/?lang=de
```

How would I have to change this redirect, if the string "?lang=de" would be optional? So for example

```
https://www.example1.com/productname
```

and I'd like to redirect this one to the en version of the site.